# Collapsing a dataframe by doing groupbys on different columns based on unique elements of another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has this structure:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'State':['NY', 'CA', 'NY', 'CA'], '3/1/20':[5, 10, 11,7], '3/2/20':[11, 13, 2,4], '3/3/20':[4, 12, 8,7]})`

and I need to keep the same structure of the pivot but "collapse" the rows by adding up all the values for each state by state so that the dataframe is transformed to:

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'State':['NY', 'CA'], '3/1/20':[16, 17], '3/2/20':[13, 17], '3/3/20':[12, 19]})`

Any suggestions on how to do this would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: `df1.groupby('State', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: Thanks, Quang! This works!